# Передача типа данных или класса в качестве параметра PHP

Tags: php

Всем добрый день. Для одного из проектов у меня стоит задача сделать LinQ-подобную выборку данных из объекта-списка. Собственно, списки хотелось бы максимально абстрагировать, но при этом не терять такой замечательной функции как автодополнение при выборке. Собственно, дабы абстрагировать это дело требуется объект самого листа, который бы в конструкторе принимал тип данных, на который он будет опираться в последствие. Внимание, вопрос =)

1. Как это лаконичнее сделать? Если передавать строку с названием типа/класса высока вероятность рукожопия при инициализации (проект делаю не один я) + отсутствует автодополнение
2. Получив тип хранимых объектов, как передать его в параметры PHPDoc'а?

Допускаю, что решение может быть нетривиальное, но идей пока что нет.

Спасибо большое!

Comment: Сделайте пример того чего вы пытаетесь добиться, так будет проще понять что вам необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, у нас есть класс SomeType и класс Dictionary, который хранит объекты абстрактного типа. При инициализации хотелось бы передать ему тип, который требуется хранить

Например (псевдокод):

```
// Конструктор класса
public function __construct($type) {
    $this->type = $type;
}

// Создание объекта класса из реализации
$dictionary = new Dictionary(SomeType);
```

Дабы словарь мог хранить только объекты класса SomeType

Далее, в PHPDoc методов словаря:

```
/**
*
*@param $key string
*
*@return %тип из $this->type
*
*/
public function get($key) {
...
return $this->objects[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если типов немного - объявить с параметрами класс:

`public class Dictionary($param1 = null,$param2 = null, ... ,$paramN = null)`

А при вызове передавать нужный тип, например:

```
Dictionary($param4);
```

А непосредственно в самом классе реализовать перегрузку